# React native having issues detecting my image path, says file does not exist

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to display an image from the directory for my project in react-native, and the following error keeps showing up and I can't figure out why. The path is right, so i'm not sure where the issue is.

I'm using this component:

```
<Image source = {require('/Slices/home\ 1/terms-of-use_02.png')} />
```

This is the error:

```
Unable to resolve module `/Slices/home 1/terms-of-use_02.png` from `/Users/Alia/Documents/Windrose Project /GroceryApp/App.js`: The module `/Slices/home 1/terms-of-use_02.png` could not be found from `/Users/Alia/Documents/Windrose Project /GroceryApp/App.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

  * `terms-of-use_02.png`
  * `/Slices/home 1/terms-of-use_02.png/index(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)`

ABI24_0_0RCTFBQuickPerformanceLoggerConfigureHooks
ABI25_0_0RCTFBQuickPerformanceLoggerConfigureHooks
<redacted>
<redacted>
<redacted>
<redacted>
<redacted>
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
UIApplicationMain
Exponent
<redacted>
```

Comment: try with a path and filename without any space f

Comment: Did any of these answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the path using following way-

```
<Image source={{uri: '-- path of Your Image here--'}}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Slices directory at the same level of App.js, try `require('./Slices/home\ 1/terms-of-use_02.png')`

Answer (score 0):

It is a very bad idea to have spaces in the folder or file names. Just rename every folder (i guess the Home 1 folder) to something like home-1 or home_1 and try again.

I am guessing the packager thinks is not an image but a module.